# What is interpretation about collecting data to obtain $P(Y|\theta)$?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I am kind of having trouble to conjure interpretation of $P(Y|\theta)$ for Bayesian statistics.

Set up an experiment of flipping coins in sequence of events. Let $Y$ be number of heads. I want $\theta$ being the probability of heads showing up. Then $P(Y|\theta)$ is reflected by "data collected". Now $\theta$ will follow some prior distribution $P(\theta)$. To estimate $\theta$, I consider posterior $P(\theta|Y)=\frac{P(Y|\theta)P(\theta)}{\int d\theta P(Y|\theta)P(\theta)}$ to obtain mean of $\theta$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ How would I collect such data? What experiment can I set up to measure $P(Y|\theta)$? Do I need a biased coin which can be tuned with probability of head being $\theta$? In reality, when one is given a single coin for experimentation, it does not seem possible to sample $P(Y|\theta)$ for all $\theta$ but only one $\theta$.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  $P(Y\,|\,\theta)$ is known...it's just the binomial distribution with parameter $\theta$.

Comment: @lulu I am asking if you are experimenter, how would you measure $P(Y|\theta)$?

Comment: It's called [Maximum Likelihood Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation).

Comment: You could, of course, sample the distribution at many values of $\theta$.  Usually though, as here, one starts from a parameterized family of known distributions, so sampling is not necessary (and would just introduce more sources of noise)l

Comment: I started typing an answer, but this topic is already [covered](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357979/how-to-optimize-the-log-likelihood-to-obtain-parameters-for-the-maximum-likeliho?rq=1).

Comment: @rtybase There are various estimators based upon different schemes. I am just concerned about how to produce an experiment to measure $P(Y|\theta)$.

Comment: @user45765 you don't know $\theta$ of the coin given. You want to estimate it from data. Conduct and experiment, literally throw the coin $N$ times and calculate how many heads showed up, say $Y$. You need to estimate what $\theta$ could produce the result or $P(Y\mid \theta)=\binom{N}{Y}\theta^Y (1-\theta)^{N-Y}$. There could be many such $\theta$. But you apply MLE and conclude that $\theta_{\text{from data}}=\frac{Y}{N}$, thus you use $$P(Y\mid \theta)=\binom{N}{Y}\left(\frac{Y}{N}\right)^Y \left(1-\frac{Y}{N}\right)^{N-Y}$$ as the likelihood in your model.

Comment: [Here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Students-Guide-Bayesian-Statistics/dp/1473916364) is a book I have in my library to "remind" me all these details :)

Comment: @rtybase Thanks for the book. The main issue of that if you were given a coin only for experimentation, you can "only" sample one $\theta$ with some "noise" assuming prior distribution with certain form. However, the task is to sample all possible $\theta,Y$ to obtain $P(Y|\theta)$. That argument seems circular somehow. The following is my thought on obtaining $P(Y|\theta)$

Comment: @rtybase  Take the coin. Start sampling by $N$ flips. Repeat experiment for $M$ times. This will give $\frac{Y}{N}$ distribution which estimates $\theta$. Now $P(Y|\theta)$ distribution can be obtained from that.